# How to specify wsdl:message name in WCF service

Tags: wcf

I've built a wcf service as defned below.  The resulting wsdl contains message names and operation input/output names that appear to be based on the message contract class name, as well as binding names and service port names that are based on the web.config binding name + the port name as defined on the service contract.

If I want specific values for message names, operation input/output names, as well as binding & port names,  how do I specify that?

```
[ServiceBehavior(
    /*Sets the wdl:service name*/ Name = "RCMR_AR000003UV01",
    Namespace = Constants.HL7v3Namespace)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public MCCI_IN000002UV01_ResponseContract GetMessage(RCMR_IN000002UV01_RequestContract query)
    {
        return ...        
    }
}

[ServiceContract(
        /*Set wsdl targetNamespae*/ Namespace ="urn:hl7-org:v3",
        /*Set wsdl portType name*/  Name = "RCMR_AR000003UV01")] 
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract( 
            /*Set wsdl request action*/  Action = "urn:hl7-org:v3/RCMR_IN000002UV01.LE20090501",
            /*Set wsdl response action*/ ReplyAction = "urn:hl7-org:v3/MCCI_IN000002UV01.LE20090501",
            /*Set wsdl operation name*/ Name = "RCMR_IN000002UV01")]
        MCCI_IN000002UV01_ResponseContract GetMessage(RCMR_IN000002UV01_RequestContract query);
    }


[System.ServiceModel.MessageContract(IsWrapped = false, WrapperNamespace = "urn:hl7-org:v3")]
public class RCMR_IN000002UV01_RequestContract
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Name = "RCMR_IN000002UV01", Namespace = "urn:hl7-org:v3")]
    public RCMR_IN000002UV01 data { get; set; }
}

[System.ServiceModel.MessageContract(IsWrapped = false, WrapperNamespace = "urn:hl7-org:v3")]
public class MCCI_IN000002UV01_ResponseContract
{        
    [MessageBodyMember(Name = "MCCI_IN000002UV01", Namespace = "urn:hl7-org:v3")]
    public MCCI_IN000002UV01 data { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/1115c3e2-3341-40da-b4ad-4bad54ab313e/